# early_stopping_rounds in lightgbm

Tags: python, lightgbm

Hi I got a problem when I used the `lightgbm` Python package in VS code:

```py
import lightgbm as lgb

parameters = {
    'application': 'binary',
    'objective': 'binary',
    'metric': 'auc',
    'is_unbalance': 'true',
    'boosting': 'gbdt',
    'num_leaves': 50,#31,
    'feature_fraction': 0.8,
    'bagging_fraction': 0.8,
    'bagging_freq': 20,
    'learning_rate': 0.003,
    'max_depth': 5,
    'verbose': 0
}
model = lgb.train(
    parameters,
    train_data_lgb,
    valid_sets=test_data_lgb,
    num_boost_round=3000,
    early_stopping_rounds=100
)
```

And the error is :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent 
call last)
c:\Users\lvn06\Desktop\ML bootcamp\Sesión 5\2. Bagging y Boosting - Clasificación.ipynb Cell 178 line 1
----> 1 model = lgb.train(parameters,
  2                 train_data_lgb,
  3                 valid_sets=test_data_lgb,
  4                 num_boost_round=3000,
  5                 early_stopping_rounds=100)

TypeError: train() got an unexpected keyword argument 'early_stopping_rounds'
```

I was looking for a solution but didn't find any.

Comment: How did you running this codes? By CPU or GPU?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please provide a minimal, reproducible example ([link to what that is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Your provided code is missing imports (what is `lgb`?) and definitions (what is in `train_data_lgb` and `test_data_lgb`?). It is also not as "minimal" as it could be...for example, try removing parameters from `params` until removing one causes the error to no longer be raise and use fewer `num_boost_round`.

Answer (score 1):

That error message suggests that you're using `lightgbm>=4.0.0`. Support for keyword argument `early_stopping_rounds` to `lightgbm.train()` was removed in `lightgbm==4.0.0` ([microsoft/LightGBM#4908](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/pull/4908))

With `lightgbm>=4.0.0`, pass validation sets and the `lightgbm.early_stopping()` callback, like in the following binary classification example:

```py
import lightgbm as lgb

from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=10_000, centers=2)

X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8)

dtrain = lgb.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train)
dvalid = lgb.Dataset(X_valid, label=y_valid)

model = lgb.train(
    params={
        "objective": "binary",
        "metric": "auc",
    },
    train_set=dtrain,
    valid_sets=[dvalid],
    num_boost_round=10,
    callbacks=[
        lgb.early_stopping(stopping_rounds=3),
    ]
)
```

Change the number of rounds by modifying argument `stopping_rounds` to `lgb.early_stopping()`.